# Why $O(\lambda_\text{max}^{\tau/2})=O(1/n^2)$ for $\tau=\frac{4\ln n}{1-\lambda_\text{max}}$?

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

It appears in the proof of Lemma 9 in 'Bounds on the cover time' by A. Z. Broder and A. R. Karlin.

Comment: Is $\lambda_{max}$ bigger than $1$ here ?

Comment: It will be helpful, if you can share link on source.

Comment: if $\lambda_1\geq\cdots\geq\lambda_n$ are the ordered eigenvalues of the chain, then $\lambda_\text{max} = \max_{2\leq i\leq n}|\lambda_i|$ and always $-1\leq \lambda_i\leq 1$ for every $1\leq i\leq n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that $0 < \lambda_{max} < 1$.

Hint : Prove that $\frac{2 ln(\lambda)} {(1-\lambda)} < -2$.

Comment: Indeed, since the graph is, by assumption, connected and not bipartite, $\lambda_\text{max}<1$. I'm not sure whether $\lambda_\text{max}>0$ holds. But I think this case is trivial and may be treated seperately.